# Blogger API missing content data

Tags: json, http, blogger

I'm currently having a major issue with the Blogger API v3.

I call for a list of blog posts like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/{blogid}/posts
```

The post content data, which should be part of the resultset is missing for some reason. All other data is there.

Is there anything on my side that could be causing this, or is this a bug on the Blogger API?

Comment: This is a bug in the Blogger API. Since about 5:00 UTC on October 8th 2013 the content parameter is missing for all blogs. Really annoying considering most of my applications are broken now.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - a work around is that the single post API endpoint still works and sends back content (`/blogId/posts/postId`), but i'm not seeing content for just the `/posts` endpoint

Comment: filed at https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5352&thanks=5352&ts=1381265106 as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bloggerdev/Qxs2APElly0:

> The `fetchBodies` parameter now defaults to false for some reason. Explicitly setting it to true fixes the issue.
>
> Here's hoping they reverse the behaviour soon.

I've confirmed that using this URL instead does return content body as it did before:

`https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/{blogid}/posts?fetchBodies=true`

Google has also confirmed that a proper fix is coming soon:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bloggerdev/hHrlcdoU0w8/znGKqSjLkRMJ

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue, you can still get the content by requesting the post specifically, when you request a blog via:

(i'm using the google webmaster blog as an example)

https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/32069983/posts?key={your key}

Each post will list a "selflink" like so:

https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/32069983/posts/5707272928466575355?key={your key}

This still shows the content, so you simply need to send an additional request to that url.

Hopefully this is only a temporary work around, as I agree it's really annoying have to make all the extra requests.